# Compute $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\left|\int_{0}^{1} x^{2} e^{i k x} d x\right|^{2}$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

> Compute $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\left|\int_{0}^{1} x^{2} e^{i k x} d
>  x\right|^{2}$

Do you have better solution for this problem without explicit compute this integral?

$\frac{e^{i k} ((1+i)-i k \log (e)) (k \log (e)+(1+i))-2
   i}{k^3 \log ^3(e)} $

Comment: Do you know Parseval's identity?

Comment: So we have $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\left|\int_{0}^{1} x^{2} e^{i k x} d x\right|^{2} = ||x^{2}||_{l_{2}}$?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the constants, you have to check them. Also, the square of the norm on the RHS should be the norm in $L^2([0,1])$, that is, $\int_0^1 x^4\,dx$.

Comment: What constants?

Comment: @Blabla: You actually have (I think) $\sum_k |\int_0^1 x^2 e^{i k x} dx|^2 = (2\pi) \int_0^1 x^4 dx$, so there appears a multiplicative factor (a constant).

Comment: Doing the integral first I find for the sum $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}| \int_0^1 x^2 e^{i k x} \,dx|^2 = \frac{2\pi}{5}$  But at the moment I see no way to simplify the explicit calculation